# Tufte-handout with fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr, tufte

I want to add a logo in the top right corner of the first page of a tufte-handout document. The code below works fine except that it puts the logo on every page except the first. What should I do?

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\title{Tufte-Handout Document with Company Logo}
\author{Baron Munchausen}

\begin{document}
\fancyhead[R]{    
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{logo.png}
}

\maketitle
\clearpage

Your content goes here.

\end{document}
```

It's evidently the `\maketitle` that is the culprit here. I suppose I can avoid using it and put the title in manually but what's the most efficient way of achieving what I want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a pagestyle with `fancyhdr` and then use that style in the titlepage.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\title{Tufte-Handout Document with Company Logo}
\author{Baron Munchausen}

\fancypagestyle{fancylogo}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{%    
        \includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image}%
        }
    }

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    \thispagestyle{fancylogo}
    
    \clearpage
    
    Your content goes here.
    
\end{document}
```

[image: output]